# Indexing a database schema outside of your control

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, view

Is there a reasonable approach to indexing a database that you don't control on a server that you do control?

We're using data from an external data vendor who delivers directly into a MS SQL Server 2008 database using programs that they wrote and we run on our server.  The specification of the database says that any alterations we make to the database may be dropped during their updates, and upon inquiry they confirm that they may drop indexes.  So we control the server, but our vendor controls the database.  The only indexes on the tables are the clustered primary keys, so the queries are very slow.

Answer (score 0):

- What I'm actually doing is a combination of indexing and replicating:  I'm attaching their PK to any of our tables that we might join to theirs.  I can speed up that process by adding indexes to their tables.  Once I get their PK, I don't care if they drop my indexes.
- I can add indexes to the tables; but if I do, I'll have to check periodically to see if they need to be redefined.
- I can replicate enough of their table into another database to act as an index (assuming no license violations)
- I considered creating a parallel database on the same server that had indexed views, but apparently an indexed view must be schema-bound within the same database.